# Attach VS debugger to executable file instead of running instance

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to attach the VS debugger to one of my own applications that is running from its installation directory in `Release` configuration.

When the app runs, it immediately shows a `MessageBox` saying that the app was launched with invalid command line arguments. These arguments have been passed to the app by the shell when an associated file (*.MyAppFileExtension) is double clicked.

The installer configures the shell to send these command lines.

Now something has gone wrong and I cannot seem to set a breakpoint after attaching the VS debugger to an instance of my app. It allows setting a breakpoint at the call to `MessageBox.Show` but by the time I attach, the call has already been executed. No breakpoints are settable after this point.

```
The error says the breakpoint failed to bind.
```

The question is, is it possible to debug the release version without going to the trouble of compiling and installing the Debug version?

Also, is it possible for the VS debugger to launch the executable itself so that valid breakpoints may be hit?

**EDIT:** In case it is relevant, the call to `MessageBox.Show` is the last line of code. Is that why breakpoints are not settable at the closing braces that follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can modify the code, the easiest way to handle this would be to add `Debugger.Launch();` (or `Debugger.Break()` to break right away) at the start of your `Main` function. This will allow you to attach a debugger as soon as the application starts.

Launching a debugging session with given command-line arguments is also possible, and quite simple - just open your project properties, go to the Debug tab, and add whatever command-line arguments you need. You can even select a different executable to launch (handy for DLLs).

Comment: Thanks. I'm already using project properties for debug testing. As for the call to `Debugger.XXX`, I don't see any of the methods marked with the `[Conditional("XXX")]` attribute. That's why I did not want to leave it in production code. I guess installing the Debug configuration is the only way I can see so far.

Comment: @RaheelKhan I don't see how that's relevant - debugging release versions of .NET code isn't really all that different from debugging debug versions. Just make sure you have the (release) PDB files. And, well, the point of `[Conditional("...")]` is that you can make your simple `DebuggerBreak` method and mark it with `Conditional` if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to debug the *installed* application you would need to first build the debug version and install that in order to be able to attach and use breakpoints. The release version lacks the debugging symbols necessary to hook into the code. If the fact that the app is installed is not relevant to what you want to test, you can set command line parameters in the project's settings and set breakpoints as normal, and then just run the app in debug mode from VS.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the purpose was to test the installed version for production. I'm already using project properties for debug testing.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add one line of code before executing other code.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

probably you just need to add on very first line of `Main` function.